# Agile database maintenance: archiving, removal of stale data strategies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A number of applications (rails 4+ over postgresql) have a few what I call application-centric present-future-looking tables, i.e. these are the tables around which the most important queries are made and require efficiency.

These also happen to be large tables with large indexes.  However, the great majority of records, if they do not lead to transactions have very little meaning to the record owner.  At most, they have meaning for statistical purposes for the administrator of the application (devising usage profiles, etc.).

So the goal is to have the minimum size of indices to speed up queries, but maintain an analytical capacity on historical data.

We have two types of data: present&future oriented (including past records that have a transaction history) and stale data for only analytical purposes.

The present thinking is the following tactic:

- create siamese models with their respective tables, i.e. circuit, circuit_twin
- maintain all relations identical between the twins and the other models (the most extreme case has 5 1-to-many relations and 3 many-to-many relations)
- run a daily routine to copy the previous period's records to the twin
- purge the main tables records of stale data for the period

**What flaws and drawbacks exist in this approach?**  There is [a ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_archive)
that appears to be doing this; however it is no longer maintained and has been developed up to rails 3.  Although I do not see this as a major task, are there any other **gem options** that accomplish the same goals?